# Python can't add to dictionary, TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'm having trouble writing a `key:value` to a dictionary. My code is fairly straight forward, I loop through an existing dictionary, calculate a score, and add that score to a new dictionary:

```
        results = {}
        for key in db:
            pickleFilePath = db[key][0]
            fileObject = open(pickleFilePath,'r')
            (kps, descs) = pickle.load(fileObject)
            fileObject.close()

            score = self.match(queryKps, queryDescs, kps, descs)

            results[key] = score
            if len(results) > 0:
                results = sorted([(v,k) for (k, v) in results.items() if v > 0],
                         reverse = True)
```

However I get this error: `TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str`. It seems to pop up after successfully adding 1 key-value to the dict. Any help appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Please show the complete or reproducible program. As it is, we cannot suggest you any solutions.

Comment: It sounds like at some point you replaced `results` with a list. It's clearly starting out as a dictionary with the code you've shown here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this line you are converting your `results` dict to a list.

```
   results = sorted([(v,k) for (k, v) in results.items() if v > 0],
                         reverse = True)
```

Then in your next loop, you will try to index `results` with a string and you will get `TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str`

Remember, usually a dict has no order sense.